# How to test without hitting database

Tags: python, django, pytest

I want to test this code without hitting the database and using pytest and pytest-mock:

```
from django.db.model import Q
from orders.models import Order


def get_orders_without_comment():    
    return Order.objects.filter(Q(comment__exact='') | Q(comment__isnull=True}))
```

Here is my test:

```
import pytest
from django.db.models import Q
from pytest_mock import mocker
from .utils import get_orders_without_comment

def test_get_orders_without_comment(mocker):
    orders_mock = mocker.patch('orders.models.Order.objects')

    orders = get_orders_without_comment()

    orders_mock.filter.assert_called_with(Q(comment__exact='') | Q(comment__isnull=True))
```

Here is the pytest exception:

```
E       AssertionError: Expected call: filter(<Q: (OR: ('comment__exact', ''), ('comment__isnull', True))>)
E       Actual call: filter(<Q: (OR: ('comment__exact', ''), ('comment__isnull', True))>)
E
E       pytest introspection follows:
E
E       Args:
E       assert (<Q: (OR: ('p...ll', True))>,) == (<Q: (OR: ('pi...ll', True))>,)
E         At index 0 diff: <Q: (OR: ('comment__exact', ''), ('comment__isnull', True))> != <Q: (OR: ('comment__exact', ''), ('comment__isnull', True))>
E         Use -v to get the full diff
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the issue by this code:

```
def test_get_orders_without_comment(mocker):
    orders_mock = mocker.patch('orders.models.Order.objects')

    orders = get_orders_without_comment()

    q1 = orders_mock.filter.call_args[0][0]
    q2 = Q(comment__exact='') | Q(comment__isnull=True)
    assert str(q1) == str(q2)
```